# How can dilation parameter a in wavelet leads to sign reversal?

Tags: wavelets

I am studying wavelets and it has been given that $$\psi_{a,b}  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|a|}} \psi (\frac{t-b}{a})$$ now the function $$ \psi(t)= 
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } 0\leq t<\frac 12\\
    -1, & \text{if } \frac 12\leq t<1\\            
0& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$
is given as in terms of previous equation $$\psi_{a,b}= \frac {1} {\sqrt{a}}[u(t-a)-2u(t-b-\frac a2)+u(t-b-a)]$$ when a>0 and
$$\psi_{a,b}=- \frac {1} {\sqrt{-a}}[u(t-a)-2u(t-b-\frac a2)+u(t-b-a)]$$ when a<0. My issue is, how can 'a' which is a dilation parameter can lead to something like a negative function when a<0?

Comment: I don't see any good reason for defining $\psi_{a,b}$ when $a \le 0$. Why would you want to do so ? And if you really want to define it, then why not like that ?

Comment: Unmentioned crosspost: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35900/how-can-dilation-of-a-wavelet-function-lead-to-its-sign-reversal